# Why can't I use .Text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new at programming and trying to build a login page as a practice. But I encounter a problem: I can't use .Text (I don't remember what this is called).

Here's the .aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginPage.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="TugasWEB.LoginPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        height: 30px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Username :
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="text" id="UsernameBox" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" id="PasswordBox" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" id="Masuk" value="Login" 
onserverclick="MasukLogin" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the .aspx.cs

```
namespace TugasWEB
{
public partial class LoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void MasukLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string username, password;
            username = "xxx";
            password = "123";

           if (UsernameBox.Text //here i cant use the .Text on my VB
        }

    }
}

}
```

I do not know if my code is wrong or if something is wrong with my Visual Studio. I am hoping that someone could help and explain what went wrong (I am following some tutorial instructions).

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You probably want `.Value`.

Comment: the .Text doesnt show up on my Visual Studio

Comment: VB? This is C# not VB.

Comment: Sorry , i mean Visual Studio .. the app im using

Comment: `<input type="text"` does not have Text property. It has `Value` property. If you want to use `Text` property then you need to have the server control. Server controls can be declared s `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UsernameBox" />`.